# many to many relationship using flask restless, post a one to many data

Tags: python, many-to-many, flask, http-post, flask-restless

My question is about how to use post to add more than one many to many relationship datas

I'm using flask, flask-SQLAlchemy, flask-restless and angularjs, json

I have some tables like this

```
class Page(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    page_name = db.Column(db.String(10)) 

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag_name = db.Column(db.String(10))

class PageTags(db.Model):
    page_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('page.id'),  primary_key=True)
    tag_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'),  primary_key=True)
    info = db.Column(db.Text)

    tag = db.relationship('Tag', backref='tag')
    page = db.relationship('Page', backref='pagetags')
```

I want to post a data like this

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "page_name": "p1",
    "pagetags": [
        {
            "info": "pt1",
            "page_id": 1,
            "tag_id": 1
        },
        {
            "info": "pt2",
            "page_id": 1,
            "tag_id": 2
        }
        ]
}
```

and I hope to add this to database which will create three things:

one page, and two pagetags.

Can I do this with restless? And How to do?

appreciate it in advance.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customizing.html#specifying-which-columns-are-provided-in-responses):

```
apimanager.create_api( Page, include_columns = [
    'id', 'page_name', 'pagetags.info', 'pagetags.page_id', 'pagetags.tag_id'
] )
```